# PHP & MySQL - How to remove first value if it is (,)

Tags: php, mysql

I have a flowing in my little project to display amount and the date from two different columns. One thing to note is that it stores multiple values in those columns which are separated by (,):

```
$apaidArray = explode(',', $apaid);
$daterArray = explode(',', $dater);

for ( $i = 0; $i < count($apaidArray); $i++ ){ 
    echo $apaidArray[$i].'&nbsp; repaid on &nbsp;' .$daterArray[$i].'<br>';
}
```

As the result of the (,) which is placed initially before the repayment amount is entered this would display the following if there are only two entries into db:

```
apaid = , 80, 20
dater = , 12.07.2017, 13.07.2017
```

Result looks like:

```
   repaid on
80 repaid on 12.07.2017
20 repaid on 13.07.2017
```

So my question is is there a way of removing the (,) before displaying result only if it is the first value in that column so that the resulting would be:

```
80 repaid on 12.07.2017
20 repaid on 13.07.2017
```

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: you need to learn about good database design practice... you should't have to store data in a csv form in the first place

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
for ( $i = 0; $i < count($apaidArray); $i++ ) { 
    if (!empty($apaidArray[$i])) {
       echo $apaidArray[$i].'&nbsp; repaid on &nbsp;' .$daterArray[$i].'<br>';
    }
}
```

Comment: Friendly reminder: Consider adding brief explanation on your answer to let OP check its usefulness.

Answer (score 5):

Run [`trim`](http://php.net/trim) on both values, with the character mask set to `','`.

Answer (score 1):

```
<?php 
$apaid = ', 80, 20';
$apaid = ltrim($apaid,','); //$apaid = ltrim($apaid,', ');
?>
```

Comment: you should add quotes around that value. that is a syntax error.

Comment: You see those values are read from db not string that's why I have wrote them like that.